# C++ Pointer to Array of Pointers (HashTable with LinkedList collision handling)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The objective is a HashTable implemented using arrays that handles collisions via LinkedList implemented with pointers. I'm a little confused as to why I am seg faulting when I go to insert. I have the following:

Classes:

```
struct Node {

  string key;
  int value;
  Node* next;

};

class HashTable{


  public:
    HashTable(int);
    //~Hash();
    void insert(string, int);
    void remove(string);

  private:
      Node** _table;
      int _table_size;
      int _hash(string);

};
```

Methods:

```
HashTable::HashTable(int size): _table_size(size) {
  _table = new Node*[size];
}

int HashTable::_hash(string key) {
  int hashValue = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<key.length();i++) {
    hashValue = 37*hashValue+key[i];
  }

  hashValue %= _table_size;
  return hashValue;
}

void HashTable::insert(string key, int value){
  int hashValue = _hash(key);

  cout << _table[hashValue]->key << endl;
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  HashTable* h = new HashTable(11);
  h->insert("test",4);
}
```

From my understanding the current value in key should be NULL should it not?

Comment: Can you run the debugger and tell which line the fault is on?

Comment: You're definitely accessing an uninitialized pointer as if it pointed somewhere useful. And for all we know, `_hash(key) >= size`

Comment: Sorry I should have included my hash function too. Its modulo tablesize so that should ensure its <= size

Comment: What does. `_hash()` return for the input value `4`?

Comment: You're definitely right about the uninitialized pointer though. Is there a quick way to initialize the entire array to NULL pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_table = new Node*[size]` creates an array of `size` uninitialized pointers, so `_table[hashValue]->key` is undefined behavior.

To initialize the entire array to `NULL`, do `_table = new Node*[size]()`. Or use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually allocated any `Node` objects.

`Node** node = new Node*[size];` allocates an arrary of `Node*`, but no actilual node objects.

Comment: It shouldn't create any objects I am looking to create an array of `Node*` initialized to `NULL` so that I may begin inserting elements into the HashTable.